Not implemented Error: Unsupported geometry encoding
I'm attempting to process a sizable number of Parquet files (362 files) in a SQL operation using the following command:
CREATE TABLE flight_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM read_parquet('*EBBR*.parquet', union_by_name='true')
);

However, when I run this line, I encounter the error Not implemented Error: Unsupported geometry encoding without any additional details.
Is there a way to obtain more information about which specific file might be causing this issue? When I work with a subset of the complete list of files, everything functions as expected.
I appreciate your help!
